# Making a hemisphere that is not at the origin

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graphics3d

I am looking to plot a mostly transparent hemisphere that has a center *not* at the origin.

I currently have:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.13], Sphere[{10, 0, 0}, 35], Axes->True}]
```

Similarly I have seen an example of how to make a hemisphere:

```
SphericalPlot3D[35,{\theta,0,Pi/2},{\phi,0,2Pi}]
```

But then it is centered at the origin. Is there a way to either translate the SphericalPlot, or a way to crop the Sphere for z>0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try experimenting with `ParametricPlot3D`, e.g. centered at `{10, 10, 10}`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v] + 10, Sin[u] Sin[v] + 10, Cos[v] + 10}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]/2},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.13],
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> True,
 ColorFunction -> (Red &),
 ViewPoint -> {100, -100, 10},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]